# How do I show/hide two separate panels using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
    function displayPanel(ddl) {
    var value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].Text;
    var value2 = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].Text;
    if (value = "News") {
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateNews.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateReview.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (value2 = "Review") {
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateReview.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateNews.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
               Article Type
            </td>
            <td>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewsCategory" runat="server" onchange="displayPanel(this)">
               <asp:ListItem Text="Select" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="News" />
               <asp:ListItem Text="Review" />
           </asp:DropDownList> 
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCreateNews" style="display:none;" runat="server">
       (Content Here)
</asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCreateReview" style="display:none;" runat="server">
     (Content Here)
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

It halfway works. I select "News" from the drop down and the News panel shows up, however if I try selecting "Review" the Review panel remains hidden.

Upon modifying the code, I am able to get the Review panel to pop up when selecting "Review". However, the News panel remains hidden upon selecting "News".

I'm so close to this, but I don't know what else to do. It looks right, but I'm most likely missing something.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you will need to use double equal for the if statement. 
try

```
 if (value == "News") {
    document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateNews.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateReview.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
}
else if (value2 == "Review") {
    document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateReview.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateNews.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
}
```

In addition, you can probably update your getElementById with the jquery id selector $("#id")

You can also show/hide items with $("#id").show() and $("#id").hide()
see [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

**Update 1:**

you will need to replace the id with your <%=pnlCreateNews.ClientID %> or <%=pnlCreateReview.ClientID %>
try this:

```
  function displayPanel(ddl) {
    var value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].Text;
    if (value == "News") {
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateNews.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateReview.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
    }
    else if (value == "Review") {
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateReview.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("<%=pnlCreateNews.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

Comment: It didn't work. I selected "News" and nothing came up. I selected "Review" and nothing came up. I did it with the "==" and original code, then with the "==" and the $("#id") selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use === for comparison instead of = and then in jquery $('#panelCreateNews).show();  or $('#panelCreateNews).hide();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if (value == "News") {
    $(#"[insertElementIDHere]").toggle();
    $(#"[insertSecondElementIDHere]").toggle();
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/